# I created a contact us form for my website but I dont know how to strore the data.(JS)

Tags: javascript, html, contact-form

I was making a new service-based website and I created the contact form. When I put my info and submit it, the website refreshes but I don't know where that information goes. I want to be able to store it somewhere, like .txt or something. Thanks in advance. (I use JS).

```
<form action="">
          <h3>get in touch</h3>
          <input type="text" placeholder="your name" class="box" />
          <input type="email" placeholder="your email" class="box" />
          <input type="tel" placeholder="subject" class="box" />
          <textarea
            placeholder="your message"
            class="box"
            cols="30"
            rows="10"
          ></textarea>
          <input onclick="alert('Thanks For Your Response')" type="submit" value="send message" class="btn" />
          <span>OR</span>
          <a
            class="btn"
            href="tel:9724005492"
            >Call Now</a
          >
        </form>
```

Comment: You will need some code running on the server to handle the form data and do something with the info.

Comment: [The  placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: a couple of questions: where are you hosting your site?, what language are you using for your backend (probably php), do you have access to a database (like mysql)?

Answer (score 1):

It goes to the URL specified in the `action` attribute.

The expectation is that you will have some server-side code ready (at that URL) to receive the data and process it.

MDN has a guide to [sending and retrieving form data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) which covers how it works and has examples for a few programming languages.

You said you were using JS. If you are using server-side JS, then it is common to use Express.js, in which case you can set up a [body parsing middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded) and then read the data from [`req.body`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body). You can then store it somewhere, which could be a text file, but it is more usual to use a database (which would handle race conditions if you ended up with simultaneous inserts).

MDN has a [Working With Forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/forms) section in their Express.js tutorial

Client-side JS can't store the data anywhere that is particularly useful for the developer of the website, but you can [add an event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for the form element's submit event and then process the data on the client. There are a few places you could store it on the client (e.g. [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)) but that will stay with the browser and not get to the person running the website.

Client-side JS could also make its own HTTP request (i.e. Ajax) to a server-side program which processes the data. The net result is the same as submitting the form to one though, just with more control over the UI.

Comment: Local store?  That could be very useful. Here’s a question do you think this person yet understands the difference between a client and a server? (Okan, hint, hint. No offense intended here)